# I am new at HTML5 Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: html, css

What is wrong here? I have to supply an id to  for a codeacademy exercise.

```
</head>
<body>

   <div class="header">
      <h1
    id="head-text"> 
      </h1>
    <div  > <!--Add an id to this div -->
     <h1> Travel Like Never Before</h1>
     <h2>Whether you're looking for adventure or luxury, let us help you 
     plan your perfect getaway.</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you wanted to add Id attributes in DIV tag?

Comment: You can simply add id attribute like: 
`<div id="myVeryPreciousId" >`

Comment: see how <h1> tag as a id attribute, just add a simpler id to the <div>, but just make the id unique.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this code

```
<div id="div_custom" > <!--  -->
     <h1> Travel Like Never Before</h1>
     <h2>Whether you're looking for adventure or luxury, let us help you 
     plan your perfect getaway.</h2>
    </div>
```

**Make sure that id is unique in page.**

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as shown below.

```
<div id="container"> <!--Add an id to this div -->
    <h1> Travel Like Never Before</h1>
    <h2>Whether you're looking for adventure or luxury, let us help you 
     plan your perfect getaway.</h2>
</div>
```